# How malloc char pointer when this one is from struct nested in other struct

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I try to `malloc` a pointer to `char` nested in few structures, but when I run the code and the `main` passes an argument that causes a `seg fault`. I cannot figure how that can happen and why it raises a `seg fault` in this case.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct s_child t_child;
struct s_child {
    char *str;
};

typedef struct s_mother t_mother;
struct s_mother {
    t_child *child;
};

// int main() { // work fine 
int main(int num, char **arg) { // cause a seg fault
    t_mother mother;
    // the malloc bellow cause a seg fault when int main() can pass arguments.
    if (!(mother.child->str = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char))))
        return (0);
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Tell me, in your own words, what does `mother.child->str` mean?

Comment: mother.child is not initialized, but you access it, resulting in [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) manifesting in a seg fault in this case.

Comment: This whole code looks weird. What are you _actually_ trying to achieve? For example `malloc(sizeof(char))` allocates memory for exactly one character, which is pretty pointless.

Comment: The typedef for s_child needs to occur after the struct definition

Comment: @Jabberwocky Just lizzy to write the length what I need to allocate, is just to reduce the code to the bug :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have declared mother, but its pointer to child is never initialized to anything.  Then you dereference that child pointer.  That is the cause of the seg fault.

Try the following:

```
int main(int num, char **arg) { // cause a seg fault
    t_mother mother;
    t_child child;

    mother.child = &child;
  // the malloc bellow cause a seg fault when int main() can pass aguments.
    if (!(mother.child->str = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char))))
        return (0);
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: You might also warn that allocating a single `char` for the `mother.child->str` string will only accommodate an empty string, and this single byte is not initialized by `malloc()`.